# Oracle query - without cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I got stuck with this query. I have table with data samples/records from sensors like this:

```
sensor | datetime       | value
----------------------------------
A      | 20140512 12:00 | 100
A      | 20140512 12:02 | 102
A      | 20140512 12:04 | 104
B      | 20140512 12:00 | 200
B      | 20140512 12:02 | 203
B      | 20140512 12:04 | 206
C      | 20140512 12:00 | 300
C      | 20140512 12:02 | 304
C      | 20140512 12:04 | 308
```

And I need to get value and previous value (alternatively increase/decrease) in given time (specified by variable) like this (time 12:02):

```
sensor | value | previous value
--------------------------------
A      | 102   | 100
B      | 203   | 200
C      | 304   | 300
```

Could anyone please help me?

Note: I dont want do use temporary cursors and teporary tables.

Thanks, Pavel

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried ?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I tried to use subquery but got ORA-01799. I'm using version 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use analytic functions for this, in particular, `lag()`:

```
select t.sensor, t.value, t.prev_value
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by sensor order by datetime) as prev_value
      from table t
     ) t
where datetime = :DATETIME;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works like a charm. It works also in cases when there are no previous values: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5a911/16/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5a911/16/0)

Answer (score 0):

A really generic (ANSI-SQL) query could be as follows.

```
SELECT
  this.*,
  prev.*
FROM
  yourTable  AS this
INNER JOIN
  yourTable  AS prev
    ON  prev.sensor   = this.sensor
    AND prev.datetime = (SELECT MAX(lookup.datetime)
                           FROM yourTable  AS lookup
                          WHERE lookup.sensor   = this.sensor
                            AND lookup.datetime < this.datetime
                        )
```

Other alternatives depend on which version of Oracle you're on.

Comment: This really works - only using **inner** join: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65826/10/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65826/10/0). But I need get all "actual" ("this") values even if there is no previous. And when using _left_ join I got ORA-01799 :-(

Comment: @user1885304 - As far as I know, `LAG()` is supported from Oracle 10g onwards.  That should work even when there is no previous value, and also be more efficient.